# Chaining actions no longer works in Protractor 5.0.0+

Tags: protractor

We recently updated Protractor from 4.0.14 to 5.3.0.  Since then we've noticed quite a few timeout errors.  After doing some digging, the timeouts occur when our tests chain together actions like : *element(by.css('someLocator').clear().sendKeys('someString')*

If I have separate lines for the clear() and the sendKeys() it works fine.  I didn't seen anything in the release notes that would have impacted this, but did I just miss something in the CHANGELOG?

Not sure if it helps, but here is the stacktrace:

```
  The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.
  </body></html>

      at parseHttpResponse (/Users/ryany337/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:536:11)
      at doSend.then.response (/Users/ryany337/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I could go through and update all the actions to not be chained but I was wondering if there was a better fix.

Answer (score 1):

In portractor 5.3.0 you will do like this

```
 element(by.css('someLocator')).clear().element(by.css('somelocator')).sendKeys('someString');
```

so it will first clear the content and then on the same location it will update 'someString' value.

Comment: That did not work for me.  The sendKeys never happens.  Isn't this essentially the same as this though (which works)?
` element(by.css('someLocator')).clear();
element(by.css('somelocator')).sendKeys('someString')
`
I can make that change for all my chained actions, but I wanted to understand if something changed post 4.014 that caused the original syntax to fail.

Answer (score 0):

element(by.css('someLocator')).clear().sendKeys('someString')
You forgot to closed bracket